# Не генерирует из wsdl заглушки для клиента

Tags: java, hibernate, wsdl, jax-ws

Есть проблема - я написал веб сервис, клиент которого адекватно генерил заглушки, и каким то образом перестал это делать. Написан сервер, рабочий сервер, у него есть wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.8 svn-revision#13980. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.8 svn-revision#13980. -->
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://util/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://util/" name="HibernateWebServiceImplService">
   <import namespace="http://service/" location="http://localhost:8080/ChallengeServer/?wsdl=1" />
   <binding xmlns:ns1="http://service/" name="HibernateWebServiceImplPortBinding" type="ns1:HibernateWebService">
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc" />
      <operation name="save">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" />
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="getUserPurchases">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" />
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="getAllProducts">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" />
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="findByUser">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" />
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="openSession">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" />
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="closeSession">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" />
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://service/" />
         </output>
      </operation>
   </binding>
   <service name="HibernateWebServiceImplService">
      <port name="HibernateWebServiceImplPort" binding="tns:HibernateWebServiceImplPortBinding">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ChallengeServer/" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

Такая структура сервера и описание сервиса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким то образом не корректно деплоится на томкат как видно из wsdl. Ниже приведу web.xml и sun-jaxws.xml:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>webservice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webservice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

</web-app>
```

**sun-jaxws.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">

    <endpoint name="HibernateWebService" url-pattern="/"
              implementation="util.HibernateWebServiceImpl"/>

</endpoints>
```

У меня есть тестовый класс, которым я проверил работоспособность подключения к бд и работой с ее данных:

```
package test;

import model.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import service.HibernateWebService;
import util.*;

public class ApplicationMainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hibernate tutorial");
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger("util/HibernateSessionFactory.java");

        HibernateWebService service = new HibernateWebServiceImpl();
        SendModel<ProductsEntity> products = service.getAllProducts();

        for (int i = 0; i < products.getList().size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(products.getList().get(i).getProductName());
        }

        SendModel<UsersEntity> user = service.findByUser("admin","admin");

        if (user != null) {
            System.out.println("Username: " + user.getUser().getUsername());
            System.out.println("Password: " + user.getUser().getPassword());
        } else {
            System.out.println("User not found!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Вывод:**

```
Hibernate: select productsen0_.idProduct as idProduc1_0_, productsen0_.productName as productN2_0_ from challenge.products productsen0_
product1
product2
product3
product4
product5
product6
Hibernate: select usersentit0_.idUser as idUser1_2_, usersentit0_.password as password2_2_, usersentit0_.username as username3_2_ from challenge.users usersentit0_ where usersentit0_.username='admin' and usersentit0_.password='admin'
Username: admin
Password: admin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не понял почему перестали генериться файлы из wsdl. Пришел к идее отката проекта и написании с работающего места все по новой. Сейчас все работает стабильно все еще.